# Store: Orders not completing

Tags: expresso-store, ee2

I posted this question a while ago under a different user - I can't comment on that one, so I'm reposting. Hope that's OK!

I'm having a problem with exp-resso whereby my client is receiving payment for orders made on the site but the orders are not appearing in the 'Orders' section of the store - they are remaining as 'Incomplete'

The first port of call would be the payment gateway, as it appears not to be flagging payment. However, the problem is appearing with both PayPal Express AND the Barclaycard EPDQ gateways.

Any pointers?

EDIT
Apparently users are getting redirected to the order confirmation page as expected, but there is no order confirmation ail generated, and the order remains at 'incomplete'

Using EE 2.53 and Store 1.6.4

Comment: Martyn - if you change the email address for both accounts to be the same, or use the same OpenID/google account to log into both accounts (i.e. add it as an alternative google login to this account), they will get automatically merged overnight.

Comment: Incomplete orders are basically still carts, so Store never completed the order. Did the payment actually go through? It's pretty much impossible for a PayPal express payment to be completed without Store marking the order as complete.

Comment: Yes, I'm not convinced it's happening for PayPal (although they insist it's all payment gateways). I'd not be too surprised if it's happening with the Barclaycard EPDQ module I wrote myself though, as I may have just missed a step in the process

Comment: Apparently it is happening with PayPal Express

Comment: So you are receiving accepted payments through paypal (money in your account), and the orders are still marked as incomplete in Store? And this is happening on every order? Have you customized the core store code on this site at all? Can you email us about this so we can take a deeper look into it?

Comment: I am having the same issue using Authorize.net. Everything works great in test mode, but once switch to production mode. Orders are taken {error:payment_method} is coming back as Your payment ... thank you for your business, client is not taken to the return page, but order remains incomplete as if it just did a cart update. Payment does go to Authrorize.net and the client is charged. Since the {error:payment_method} is coming back as Your payment ... thank you for your business, I am assuming that the response came back, but Store is not completing the order.

Comment: Thanks Adrian - I'm going to set up a mirror site for testing to see if I can recreate. If there is definitely an issue I'll mail you direct.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost impossible for payments to be collected with Paypal and yet the order to remain incomplete. Paypal doesn't actually collect the funds until Store marks the order as complete. So that seems unlikely - I would check with your client and find exact steps to reproduce the problem.

With some other gateways, they only notify Store of the payment success, and there is a possibility the payment may go through but Store's notification URL is not called successfully. This could either be because the gateway didn't call the URL, or because your site blocked it for whatever reason.

Often a good place to start when debugging this sort of thing is to look at your server access logs and see if you can see the gateway calling the correct `index.php?ACT=` URL on your site, right after an order is completed. That will tell you whether or not your site is receiving the message or whether the problem is with the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd just update this, as other people may find it useful

It turns out that the reason this started failing was that Barclaycard had done a major upgrade and migration of their payment system. They had informed the merchant, but the merchant, in their wisdom, didn't think it necessary to inform me!

I can't believe that they didn't associate the transactions failing with the email from Barclaycard informing them of a major system upgrade.

D'Oh!